# Laravel, Carbon. Get count of hours for a specific month between dates

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

How to get the number of hours referring only to the one month between 2 dates?
For example, how to get count of hours for December for first or for second row at the screenshot?

[image: DB screenhsot]

I tried this (subMonths generated in the loop, so no worry about it):

```
$bookings = Booking::whereDate('departure_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonths($i)->startOfMonth())
                   ->orWhereDate('arrival_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->subMonths($i)->endOfMonth())->get();
```

and then:

```
foreach ($bookings as $book) {
   echo Carbon::parse($book->departure_date.$book->departure_time)->diffInHours(Carbon::parse($book->arrival_date.$book->arrival_time));
}
```

But in this case I get count of hours for whole booking, how to get it only for December?

p.s. I need this for calculating the statistics (booking percentage).

Comment: Sidenote: `->diffInHours()` returns a whole number (rounded), so don't rely on that for exact values.

Answer (score 0):

You would likely need to `->addMonth()` then go to the `->startOfMonth()` then use `diffInHours()`.

```
Carbon::parse($book->departure_date)
    ->addMonth()
    ->startOfMonth()
    ->diffInHours(Carbon::parse($book->arrival_date.$book->arrival_time));
```

I've omitted `$book->departure_time` otherwise the timestamp wouldn't be the first second of the first day of the month.